# How to charge the grenade launcher of Demoman?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-demoman

When I was playing Team Fortress 2 I got to charge the grenade launcher of the Demoman class. When I hold the left button, Demoman puts a lot of ammo on the launcher and release them all at once. But then when I played again I can't do it anymore.

Comment: Check in the controlls to which key "reload" is bound too. You tried "R" already? Has been a long time since i played TF, i'm sorry if this does not help you.

Comment: Perhaps the reload animation was looping. This is quite common in TF2, but has no in-game effect.

Comment: It could have also been a custom mod on the server that had some kind of weapon modification.  Alternatively, you may be thinking of the beggar's bazooka.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The demoman has no ability to fire multiple bombs at once but can detonate many or all grenades at once using secondary fire.

He can charge shots by holding down primary fire. On primary fire release he will fire the bomb a distance proportional to the amount of time primary fire is held down. This only works with the three sticky bomb launchers.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I just encountered an animation loop like what Austin Mohr said. Btw thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

No Demoman weapon in Team Fortress 2 can fire multiple projectiles simultaneously, so it's unclear what it is you're looking for.

- The [Beggar's Bazooka](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Beggar's_Bazooka) for the Soldier functions as you describe. Perhaps you were actually playing Soldier?
- (I've got a dim memory of seeing a video where someone did do that, but I don't recall any more details. Still, it must have been a mod or something.)

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of this video?: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LF2mlZgI4WI In which case yes it is a mod.

Comment: A little on my mind I think it's a mod in a server. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I know this has already been answered, but I came upon the same thing while playing on the 10x servers. The 10x servers add a great deal of functionality to to weapons, including the specific effect noted in the question.

A complete list of changed on these servers can be found on the tf2 wiki: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/TF2_x10